# how to store variable values over multiple page loads

Tags: php

I'm making a php script that stores 3 arrays: `$images`, `$urls`, `$titles` based on the input data of the form within the php file.

I want to print the values of these arrays in the first part of the page and then to pre-fill the form's input fields with the value of the arrays. Also when a user modifies an input field and clicks on "Save" the page should reload with the modfied version.

My problem is that on each call of the php file in a browser the value of the variables gets deleted. Is there a way to store the values of the array so that the form always gets pre-filled with the last saved values?

```
<?php
//save the arrays with the form data
$images = array($_POST["i0"],$_POST["i1"],$_POST["i2"],$_POST["i3"]);
$urls = array($_POST["u0"],$_POST["u1"],$_POST["u2"],$_POST["u3"]);
$titles = array($_POST["t0"],$_POST["t1"],$_POST["t2"],$_POST["t3"]);
//print the arrays
print_r($images);
print_r($urls);
print_r($titles);
//create the form and populate it
echo "<p><form method='post' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."';";
$x = 0;
while ($x <= 3) {
   echo"<div>
            <input name='i".$x."' type='text' value='".$images[$x]."'>
            <input name='u".$x."' type='text' value='".$urls[$x]."'>
            <input name='t".$x."' type='text' value='".$titles[$x]."'>";
       $x++;
}
?>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Save"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: this script isn't correlated with any database, it doesn't send out data and it doesn't modify any other pages. What's the worst thing that could happen in case on an XSS attack?

Comment: A user stealing cookies from your domain?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Store the variables in a PHP session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['images'] = $images;
```

Then on next (or any other) page, you can retrieve the values as:

```
session_start();
$images = $_SESSION['images'];
```

Comment: does this apply if I'm retrieving the values on the same page in the `//print the arrays` section of my code?

Comment: Yes. Once you set the variables in session, you can access it on the same page as well

Comment: it didn't work in my case. I added `session_start();$_SESSION['images'] = $images;` after the step: `//save the arrays with the form data`
And then I added `session_start();$images = $_SESSION['images'];` before `//create the form and populate it`

Comment: What didn't work? Session should work fine. Please check your values. For example, run this code: `$name = "Vikk"; session_start(); $_SESSION['name'] = $name; echo $_SESSION['name'];` It will print `Vikk`

Comment: when I said it didn't work I meant that after I completed my form and I clicked "Save", I copy&pasted the url to my php file in the browser and the values of the variables were null. PS=can `$_SESSION['name']` store an array? and if yes what's the syntax? is it like `$_SESSION['name'][0]` etc?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the scope of the variables to a larger scope, might do the trick. Also, check if you have a post request before updating the values.

```
<?php
    if(sizeof($_POST) >0)
    {
      //UPDATE VALUES
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a permanent storage of state, between *different* pages, you should use sessions, by putting `session_start();` in the start of your script. After this, every variable $_SESSION[$x] will be persisted, and will be available to your scripts.

However, in this particular case, answering your question: "Is there a way to store the values of the array so that the form always gets pre-filled with the last saved values?", it is easier to just use the $_POST variable if it exists already:

```
<?php
if(!$_POST){
    $_POST = array();
    foreach(array("i0","i1","i2","i3") as $i) $_POST[$i]="";
    foreach(array("u0","u1","u2","u3") as $i) $_POST[$i]="";
    foreach(array("t0","t1","t2","t3") as $i) $_POST[$i]="";
}
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)  filter_input(INPUT_POST,$k,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

//save the arrays with the form data
$images = array($_POST["i0"], $_POST["i1"], $_POST["i2"], $_POST["i3"]);
$urls   = array($_POST["u0"], $_POST["u1"], $_POST["u2"], $_POST["u3"]);
$titles = array($_POST["t0"], $_POST["t1"], $_POST["t2"], $_POST["t3"]);


//print the arrays
print_r($images);
print_r($urls);
print_r($titles);
//create the form and populate it
echo "<p><form method='post' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."';";
$x = 0;
while ($x <= 3) {
   echo"<div>
            <input name='i".$x."' type='text' value='".$images[$x]."'>
            <input name='u".$x."' type='text' value='".$urls[$x]."'>
            <input name='t".$x."' type='text' value='".$titles[$x]."'>";
       $x++;
}
?>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Save"><br>
</form>
```

Note: this line `foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)  filter_input(INPUT_POST,$k,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);`
should be enough to protect you from basic XSS attacks.
Note also that in general, it is best to follow the [pattern of reloading pages with GET after POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), which makes you less susceptible to form resubmitions, in which case using sessions for storage is the better solution.

Comment: filter-input requires the version of the PHP interpreter to be >= 5.2.0 (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php )

You can safely remove the line that contains it, if you use other ways to sanitize your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

What brought me here was somewhat different kind of beast. I had problem with subsequent post request from AXIS IP camera and needed to preserve last file name across requests. In case that someone stumble here looking for some way to cache variables and SESSION is not an option maybe should look at Alternative PHP Cache:

> Note: Unlike many other mechanisms in PHP, variables stored using
>   apc_store() will persist between requests (until the value is removed
>   from the cache).

http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) to store values and write rules to refill form fields after validations on data submit. Also function [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is very helpful to avoid "not defined" errors.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is the session. Use `$_SESSION` to store value of Your variables. For example, at the end of script:

```
$_SESSION['images'] = $images;
```

and in form's input:

```
<input name='i".$x."' type='text' value='".(isset($_SESSION['images']) ? 
$_SESSION['images'] : '')."'>
```