# Store Array Variables Through Page Refresh with PHP

Tags: php

So this is the second assignment in a beginner PHP class. One part of the assignment requires you to allow the user to enter in multiple walls in an HTML form (the program is a calculator to figure out the cost of paint, labor, etc.), however you don't know how many walls the person is going to enter, so the form needs to be dynamic.

I don't think we're allowed to use javascript.

I've tried to use the SESSION variable to store the values into an array ( [how to store variable values over multiple page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964917/how-to-store-variable-values-over-multiple-page-loads) ) and use foreach functions to loop and save the data ( [How to store values from foreach loop into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045619/need-to-store-values-from-foreach-loop-into-array) ).

Nothing seems to be working. In this assignment we're not supposed to use SQL.

Is there another way to store an array? I'd also be happy with a way to echo the data and leave it there until the cache is cleared.

Here's the code I  have right now (sorry it's a bit of a mess):

```
print_r($_POST);
      echo "<br />";
      print_r($_REQUEST['wallW']);
      echo "<br />";

      echo "<br />";
      $wallW = $_REQUEST['wallW'];         
      echo "The width is $wallW.";
      echo "<br />";      
      print_r($wallW);

       $_SESSION['wallW'] = $wallW;
        $wallW = $_SESSION['wallW'];


    ?>


            <form name="getOrderInfo" action="" onsubmit="" method="post">
            <table id="wallInfo">
                <th>
                    Order Information
                <th>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Wall Width:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="wallW[]" id="wallW" size="20"  value="">
                    </td>
                <tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Wall Length:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="wallL[]" id="wallL" size="20"  value="">
                    </td>
                <tr>

            </table>


        <input type="submit" value="Add Wall">
</form>
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks,
Chelsea

Comment: store $_POST as varible in $_SESSION

Comment: I tried doing it like this: `$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST;` then calling the data with: `print_r($data);` as well as `print_r($_POST);`. Doesn't seem to be working. I know the sessions should work...I think I'm just not setting them up right somehow.

Comment: check my answer do it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use `session_start();` on the top of the file, then `$_SESSION['array'] = $array;`.

Comment: I've tried both `session_start(); $_SESSION['wallW'] = $wallW; $wallW = $_SESSION['wallW'];` and 'session_start(); $_SESSION['wallW'] = $wallW;` but both ways just overwrite the array.

Comment: var_dump($wallW); what does this give you?

Comment: Okay, this answered my get-variables-through-refresh. Now I'm working on adding variables to the arrays. I'll post that question in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

store

```
$data =  $_POST;
$_SESSION['data'] = $data;
```

and check on next page

```
if(isset($_SESSION['data'))
{
$data = $_SESSION['data'];
print_r($data);
}
```