# Add to A $_POST Array through Multiple Refreshes

Tags: php

I need to be able to store the $_POST data from a form (I'm doing that with the SESSION variable) and I need to add data to the $_POST array without overwriting the previous data.

Here's my original thread about the SESSION variables: [Store Array Variables Through Page Refresh with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699824/store-array-variables-through-page-refresh-with-php)

Here's an example of what I need to do:

There's a form on a page that you can put the width and height of a wall to calculate out how much paint/labor would be needed to paint the walls. Once the first wall dimensions are entered, the user can click the submit button labeled "Add Wall" to add another wall to their order.

After the first wall input, the POST data would return something like this:

```
Array ( [wallW] => Array ( [0] => 9 ) [wallL] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) )
```

After the second wall is entered it would look something like this:

```
Array ( [wallW] => Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 20 ) [wallL] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 15 ) )
```

This would continue on until the user has entered all of their walls.

I've tried doing `array_merge`, `array_append`, etc, but none of those seem to be working; it keeps overwriting what's tin the POST data, even if I bring the POST data into another array.

I know the easy thing would be to throw some jQuery in there, but this is for a PHP class (and we're not allowed to use SQL yet) so I'd like to try to figure this out with just PHP.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks,

Chelsea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this has been downvoted, i find it rude as you are obviously new to php. But you just need to re-post your post vars in subsequent requests. So you would need to serialize you existing post objects as perhaps hidden fields. What you are missing is that php / http is stateless. So nothing is preserved between requests, another easy solution may be to move these POST variables to SESSION variables.

I see you've added the POST data to the session, but there is no reason to add it back to post, just keep appending to session and then use it from there. adding things to _POST wont force them to be posted next time if thats you are trying todo, see the part about serializing them to hidden fields.

Good luck, welcome to programming for the web.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are constructing array seems little odd to me. Instead I would do something like.

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $wall = array('w' => $_POST['w'], 'h' => $_POST['h']);
    $_SESSION['walls'][] = $wall;
}
```

Please give this a try.